# How to make my toy android calculator UI fits with the device screen

Tags: android, grid-layout

I want to create a simple calculator as my first android project (instead of Helloworld), the calculaotr UI is shown below, which I uses `GridLayout` to arrange the result display `TextView` and the control `Button`s, the `GridLayout` takes 6 rows and 4 columns. ( I simplified the xml layout file here)

```
<GridLayout android:rowCount="6" 
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/expressionTextView"
              android:layout_columnSpan="4"/>
    <LinearLayout
              android:layout_columnSpan="4">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnClearText"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnDeleteText"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 <GridLayout>
```

[image]

For creating the `+/-/x//0-9.` buttons, I use the following code:

```
String[] buttonTexts = new String[] 
{
    "7", "8", "9", "/",
    "4", "5", "6", "x",
    "1", "2", "3", "-",
    ".", "0", "=", "+"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Point size = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight = size.y;
    int oneQuarterWidth = (int) (screenWidth * 0.25);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < buttonTexts.length; ii++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText(buttonTexts[ii]);
        btn.setTextSize(40);

        GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(ii/4 + 2);
        GridLayout.Spec columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(ii % 4 );
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpec, columnSpec);
        params.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
        params.width = oneQuarterWidth;
        gridLayout.addView(btn, params);
    }
```

However, the last row stretches on the vertical direction, and when running the calculator on my android machine, some of the last row may be hidden!

What I want is to make the UI fits with the device height, do you have any ideas? Thanks!

P.S.
I even tried to set the heights of the result display `TextView` and `LinearLayout` that contains `Clear/Del` by using:

```
expressionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expressionTextView);
clearDelLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

GridLayout.LayoutParams expressionTextViewParams =
     (GridLayout.LayoutParams)expressionTextView.getLayoutParams();
expressionTextViewParams.height = ...; // some calculated height
expressionTextView.setLayoutParams(expressionTextViewParams);
```

But this doesn't work :(

Comment: do you mean horizontal direction?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I used horizontal direction actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from documentation:

> Limitations:
>
> GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of
>   weight, as defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible
>   to configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space between multiple
>   components. Some common use-cases may nevertheless be accommodated as
>   follows. To place equal amounts of space around a component in a cell
>   group; use CENTER alignment (or gravity). For complete control over
>   excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout
>   subview to hold the components in the associated cell group. When
>   using either of these techniques, bear in mind that cell groups may be
>   defined to overlap.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

try using LinearLayouts for the children, like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
<Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnClearText" />
```

Or you can simply use another layout, like e.g. `LinearLayout`, which is pretty consistent when it comes to rendering

P.S.

from docs:

> a call to setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams) must be made to
>   notify GridLayout of the change

Maybe after changing layout parameters, you should call `GridLayout.invalidate();` ?

Comment: I just wonder is there any way to set the GridLayout cell with a calculated height which will make everything fit perfectly?

Comment: @ZhiWang try to call invalidate on your GridLayout after you change layout parameters

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the limitation, I also think using nested linearlayout can solve this problem.